# D'où vient vraiment ce « i grec » ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire, alphabet, grec

Certes en français on prononce souvent cette lettre `[i]` lorsqu'elle est employée en tant que voyelle, mais le [Υ](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_%28lettre%29) semble plutôt dérivé du *upsilon* grec. En allemand la lettre est bien appelée *upsilon* et se prononce en général `[y]` (comme la lettre *u* en français).

Qu'est-ce qui peut expliquer cette appellation en français ? La prononciation aurait changé et le nom de la lettre aurait suivi ? L'appellation qui en résulte n'est-elle pas incohérente ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comme le note Grevisse, le *upsilon* des Grecs était transcrit par un *i* en Latin, tout simplement. Les Romains appelaient la lettre (qu’on retrouvait, par exemple et par analogie avec le Grec, dans la graphie alternative *sylva*) *I graeca*, d'où le nom moderne.

Comment: Dans Grevisse (14e ed., dans mon cas), c'est la §96, Note historique, la section couvrant l'origine des usages de la lettre, très intéressant (du moins si ce genre de trucs vous intéressent XD). J'admet que la confirmation du nom latin et l'exemple sont empruntés à Wikipédia en anglais, car je n'ai pas sous la main de sources plus prestigieuses que je puisse citer.

Answer (score 4):

De mémoire. Le upsilon grec a été importé deux fois dans l'alphabet latin, une fois comme `u` et une fois comme `y` (et le `u` s'est séparé du `v` vers le XVIIième siècle me semble-t'il). La forme `y` n'était utilisée que pour des mots empruntés et, au moins dans certains cas, déjà prononcée `/i/`. Je n'ai aucune idée de comment les Grecs la prononçait, ni même si cette prononciation était unique (dans l'écriture, dans le temps et dans l'espace — les dialectes variaient aussi dans la prononciation).

Comment: La prononciation en grec ancien (reflétée par celle de l’allemand moderne) est celle du u français, ce qui explique que ce son s'écrive justement /y/ en alphabet phonétique.